# Postgres FTS with array of composite types

Tags: database, postgresql, full-text-search, relational-database, data-modeling

Say I have the following psuedo-schema, where the `1-many` relation is modeled using Postgres arrays :

```
CREATE TYPE quotes AS
(
  text  CHARACTER VARYING,
  is_direct CHARACTER VARYING
);

CREATE TABLE posts
(
    body  CHARACTER VARYING,
    q     quotes[]
);
insert into posts(body,q) VALUES('ninjas rock',ARRAY[ ROW('I AGREE',True)::quotes, ROW('I DISAGREE',FALSE)::quotes ]);
```

**My first question is:** how do I perform a select to filter out the `quote->text` from the entire array.

This works :

```
test=# select body, q[1].text from posts;
     body     |  text   
--------------+---------
 hassan rocks | I AGREE
(1 row)
```

But this doesn't (note that the entire composite type is being retrieved) :

```
test=# select body, (q).text from posts;
     body     |                      text                       
--------------+-------------------------------------------------
 hassan rocks | {"(\"I AGREE\",true)","(\"I DISAGREE\",false)"}
(1 row)
```

**To bridge onto my real question**, how would I create a gin or gist (with or without `to_tsvector`) index which includes the text of both the post body as well as all of the quote text ? I Prefer not to go with the extra column approach of indexing as triggers [make me sad](http://ktulu.com.ar/god-kills-a-kitten-generator/index.php?txt=Rirelgvzr%20n%20gevttre%20vf%20hfrq%20va%20n%20eryngvbany%20fpurzn&lang=en).

Currently my schema represents the post and quote as a `1-many` relation, however I think if postgres supports what I am trying to do it would simplify things drastically.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to get the array parts and returns as a `SETOF quotes` and call the funcion on the `SELECT`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getquote(posts)
RETURNS SETOF quotes
LANGUAGE sql
AS $getquote$
SELECT $1.q[i].text, $1.q[i].is_direct
FROM generate_series(array_lower($1.q, 1), array_upper($1.q, 1)) AS i
$getquote$
```

And the `SELECT` would be:

```
SELECT body, (getquote(p)).* FROM posts p;
```

You could create a view to make things easier, and you can also do filter tasks on the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will "filter" your array. `select (unnest(q)).text from posts;`. `unnest` pivots the array into rows. Notice that `unnest` is wrapped in parenthesis, this is important because without the parenthesis you wouldn't be able to select specific fields -- i.e., `unnest(q).text` is invalid and `unnest(q)` itself results in a row containing the composite in string form.

The code to treat the post txt and the quote txt's as a single unit of text is as follows :

```
SELECT to_tsvector(q.b_txt || q.q_t) FROM
(
    SELECT b_txt,string_agg(p.q_txt,' ') as q_t 
    FROM ( SELECT 1 AS id,body b_txt, (unnest(q)).text AS q_txt FROM posts) AS p 
    GROUP BY p.id,b_txt
) AS q;
```

This probably needs to be adapted into a UDF for use in `gin` or `gist` indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer part 1.

To return a row for each body/quote:

```
SELECT body, q_unnest.text AS quote
FROM posts, UNNEST(q) AS q_unnest
```

To return a row for each post with an array of quote texts:

```
SELECT posts.body, array_agg(q_unnest.text) AS quotes
FROM posts, UNNEST(q) AS q_unnest
GROUP BY posts.body
```

To return a row for each post with quote texts separated by a delimiter:

```
SELECT posts.body, array_to_string(array_agg(q_unnest.text), '|') AS quotes
FROM posts, UNNEST(q) AS q_unnest
GROUP BY posts.body
```

I setup an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/052cd/11) so you can try it for yourself.

As for part 2 and indexing an array of composite types, I believe it requires an "Operator Class", as per the Postgres extensions guide [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/xindex.html).  That looks like a lot of bother to me and I haven't found an example of how to do it.